# How to get a robot arm to follow the topography of a 3D mesh?

Tags: navigation, robotic-arm, arm-navigation

First time on here, really stuck with my project at the moment. I am looking to find out how to get a KUKA robot I am using to follow a path along the vertices of a mesh of a human that I have. I have been planning to utilise path planning algorithms which will allow the robot to be able to navigate the topography of the meshes chest.
I just do not know how to implement this given it is a 3D problem.
I have imported the mesh into MATLAB etc but cannot find out how to generate a path.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* EnginJam. I'm afraid it's not clear what exactly you need help with. On first reading, my reaction was to explain that you would project a line onto the surface of the mesh, but then I realized you could just pull vertices from the mesh itself. I can't tell if you're having difficulty determining how to get a list of points, or if you need help understanding what to do with those points once you have them (inverse kinematics).

Comment: Hi Chuck, appreciate the swift help! I essentially am struggling how to create a path which follows the vertices. E.G. on MATLAB I cannot find how to do this for a 3D mesh. Path planning algorithms are easily done on 2D scenarios but figuring out how to do this for a 3d mesh is what Im struggling with. @Chuck

Comment: If it helps, the project is to get a KUKA iiwa R820 to trace a path along the surface of a human mannequins chest. I am exploring the idea of following the mesh vertices as a way for the robot to be able to navigate the topography of the mannequin. Hope this helps :) Again, really appreciate the help @Chuck

Comment: Can you link documentation on what you're doing for 2D path planning? 3D is "just" 2D with an extra dimension, and it's still not clear to me which part of the problem is giving you trouble. [Here's the Mathworks documentation on a path planner](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nav/ref/plannerrrt.html) which can use an [SE3 state vector](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nav/ref/statespacese3.html), but this is assuming you want to give start and end coordinates and have the system solve the path. What I'm saying is you can just sample the vertices directly and make a list of waypoints from those.